# JavaScript, add and not replace

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

first of I would like to thank you for taking your time and reading my question.

This is my script

```
    function SetDate(dt) {
   if(document.getElementById("isoDate").checked) {
        $('#date').val(dt);
    }
}
```

And here is my dates:

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
    var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate"onclick="javascript:SetDate('@isoDate');" />
        @*<a href="javascript:SetDate('@isoDate');">@isoDate</a>*@
    </div>
}
```

Right now, when I check the checkbox with the date it will add the date, but when I check another date it will replace that old date.

What I Want to is when I check several dates I want to add it like this:

```
yymmdd,yymmdd,yymmdd or yymmdd yymmdd yymmdd
```

And when I uncheck a box I want it to remove the date.

Comment: where is your #date element?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich Is that necessary? It already adds the dates to the textfield, but I do not want the next date to replace the old once, I want it to get added like yymmdd,yymmdd, and when I uncheck the box I want that date to get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use Array in your case because you need add or remove date based on selection.

```
var dateArr=new Array();
function SetDate(dt) {
   if(document.getElementById("isoDate").checked) {
       if(dateArr.indexOf(dt)<0){ // check if date already added. if not then add it to array.
          dateArr.push(dt); 
       }          
    }else{
         var index=dateArr.indexOf(dt);
         if (index > -1) {
           dateArr.splice(index, 1);//Remove from array if checkbox uncheck
         }       
      }
     $('#date').val(dateArr.join(",")); // Add coma separated string to you #date element.     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution doesn't really work. It works great for check the boxes, but when I uncheck 1 box it won't remove the date. If I want to remove a date I will have to remove the first date I added, than I can remove the others. But I do get the idea behind it and I believe I manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be:

```
// Get current value
var dateValue = $('#date').val(); 
// Add value to current and remove spaces around
var newValue = (dateValue + " " + dt).trim();
// Set new value
$('#date').val(newValue);
```

Comment: edit the line var newValue = (dateValue + " " + dt).trim(); to var newValue = (dateValue + "," + dt).trim();